# Why does background-size:cover act differently on mobile?

Tags: html, css

I'm having an issue with background-size: cover on mobile devices (tested on mobile safari and android).

There are times in which the height of my webpage changes when the user expands a more info box. Whenever that happens on mobile the background image actually zooms in. On desktop it does not.

I worked around this issue by adding a "scrollable" layer in the CSS, but this introduced more issues.

Any suggestions on how to fix this, or is the "scrollable" layer my only option?

I believe that the mobile browsers are simply adjusting the background to be what it would look like if the site initially loaded at the "expanded" size, however, on desktop it does not do this.

Comment: my understanding of background-size: cover is that it is implemented in each browser somewhat differently...

Answer (score -1):

Using responsive design might help you to get rid of these issues, the method is design for developer who creating a website for both desktop and mobile device.

I will give out an example:

In your CSS you have:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
.hide {
    display:none;
}}
```

In your PHP/HTML you have

```
<p class="hide"> tester 1234 </p>
```

These will let your display your text when the screen size is bigger than 700px, disappear if smaller than 700px.

I think you should be able to do some modify for you codes by now, hope this help.

Reference  : http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

Comment: _“These will let your display your text when the screen size is bigger than 700px, disappear if smaller than 700px.”_ – the question was not about that; it was about a specific problem with a background image and `background-size:cover`.

Comment: i am giving our an example , thank you for your negative attitude to all my answers and vote down my answer. Why don't u answer them my good sir. if you not gonna help please step away

Comment: The issue is that the background actually appears to "zoom" when background-size: cover is used because on mobile it is adjusting the background to be a bigger webpage rather than just revealing more of the background image like on mobile. Thanks for your answer though...I'm definitely using responsive design as I have media queries for other elements on the web page.